# Imacros Eval function Small Help Required

Tags: javascript, imacros

Hello Please Help Me with this

this is middlle snippet of the whole script ( numbering and asterisk only for reference )

```
1) ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\MyFiles\ FILE=captcha.jpg WAIT=YES
2) TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR = *******
3) *****
4) ****
5) ***
6) SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}
7) TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:CAPTCHABox ATTR=ID:tokentext CONTENT= {{!EXTRACT}}
8 TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:continue
```

Then after step 8

I want it to check for this element

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H1 ATTR=TXT:Check
```

if it exists then move forward to the next lines of the code ( step 9, 10 etc ) else if it does not exists or gives an error then i want it to repeat steps from 1 to 8 and then check again, if element is absent again repeat 1-8 else move forward to step 9 and so on..

i think EVAL function can be used in it , can you please provide the correct code ? i have tried a lot of times but failed

P.s - I am already looping whole script from .vbs if possible please provide code that can be used in .iim only

Please Reply

thank you very very much

Edit - this is my .vbs code

```
Option Explicit

Dim iim1, i, s , shell
dim iret
dim myname, mypath
dim pos


'initialize iMacros instance
set iim1= CreateObject ("iMacros")



'i = iim1.iimOpen ("-fx", false) 'Use open Firefox instance if available
i = iim1.iimOpen ("-fx", true) 'Always open new instance

pos = 2

Do while pos < 5



iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")


set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\Users\SDFL\Desktop\dc1.bat"

pos = pos + 1
loop
```

Please tell me how i can do this without disturbing the main loop and bat file ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in pure IIM script, since it does not have ability to loop code inside the code.
you need to manage looping and verification in javascript or main vbs code, but not with EVAL inside IIM code

Comment: thanks a lot for reply , i understand that but can't we apply manual loop like instead of looping write the code we want to repeat
something like this
if ( element ) exists continue
else {1) ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=C:\MyFiles\ FILE=captcha.jpg WAIT YES...
8 TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:continue 
     then again inside the main if else statement 

{{if ( element ) exists   continue
else { steps from 1 to 8 code manually inserted) all inside EVAL something like this instead of main looping i just require if else function to work in this , since i need to repeat this only 2- 3 times Please Reply Sir

Comment: sir i have updated my post with my .vbs script can you help me with it now ? if iim returns an error then repeat the previous step without disturbing main loop and bat file.